# how to have a task run when 'value' not in ansible fact

Tags: ansible

I have not been able to find how do a when statement a fact does not match.

This is what i have so far:

Here is the task:

```
- name: Set Percentage value to "yes" to all attached disks, for non-'nfsutil' servers
  shell: |
    NUM=$(cat -n {{ file_path }} |\
          sed -n "/<disk>/,/<\/disk>/p" |\
          sed -n "/<alarm>/,/<\/alarm>/p" |\
          sed -n "/<fixed>/,/<\/fixed>/p" |\
          sed -n "/<{{ item }}>/,/<\/{{ item }}>/p" |\
          awk '/ percent = no/ {printf "%d", $1}')"s";
    if [ "${NUM}" != "s" ]; then
        sed -i "${NUM}/no/yes/g" {{ file_path }};
        echo "file_was_changed" ;
    fi
  with_items: "{{ nfsfs.stdout_lines }}"
  register: threshold_yes
  when: '"nfsutil01" not in ansible_hostname or "nfsutil02" not in ansible_hostname'
  changed_when: '"file_was_changed" in threshold_yes.stdout'
```

Where the setup module for both servers shows:

```
"ansible_hostname": "nfsutil01"
"ansible_hostname": "teachphp01"
```

The goal is to perform this activity, using the same inventory list on only for 'teachphp01.my-domain.net' in the below case.

```
TASK [Set Percentage value to "yes" to all attached disks, for  non-'nfsutil' servers]    
***************************************************************************    
***************************************************************************
ok: [nfsutil01.my-domain.net] => (item=#)
ok: [teachphp01.my-domain.net] => (item=#)
ok: [teachphp01.my-domain.net] => (item=#tmp)
ok: [nfsutil01.my-domain.net] => (item=#tmp)
ok: [teachphp01.my-domain.net] => (item=#boot)
ok: [nfsutil01.my-domain.net] => (item=#boot)
```

When I test this however it runs on both servers instead of skipping nfsutil01 and running on teachphp01.

Comment: what is the value of `ansible_hostname`? and what output do you expect/and what do you get?

Comment: ansible_hostname would have a value of of the name of the server... in this case it could be anything from "myservername" to "123sfasdfbsdfa"..  i'm not sure if I need any output, i just want to not execute this specific task if the value of ansible_hostname is 'myservername' or 'myservername2'

Comment: sure, but I have tried your code and it seems to work as expected. so for what concrete values does it not work?

Comment: updated with concrete values

Answer (score 1):

The "if not in list" idiom should solve this:

```
when: ansible_hostname not in ["nfsutil01", "nfsutil02"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess this is a problem with the boolean expression, not with ansible.

`"nfsutil01" not in ansible_hostname or "nfsutil02" not in ansible_hostname'`

evaluates to true because `nfsutil02` is not in`"nfsutil01"`...

maybe you want to do

```
when: '"nfsutil01" not in ansible_hostname and "nfsutil02" not in ansible_hostname'
```

BTW, using `in` in that way means you are searching for substrings, which may not be what you want.